# How to return specific scope according to given user role in Curity

Tags: curity

Given :

- a oauth client using Authorization code flow used by a website to fetch resources from an API located behind a Reverse Proxy,
- some users with differents roles (*admin* & *customer*) defined in the roles part of the SCIM 2.0 User schema in Curity
- a custom claim '*roles*' based on the '*roles[]*' field retrieve from the account-manager-claims-provider
- two scopes (*product_read* & *product_write*)

**How can we attached the right scope based on a given role for an unique client in Curity to get :**

- the product_**read** scope for all users with '*customer*' role
- the product_**write** scope for all users with '*admin*' role

Curity docs or videos talk about custom mapper for claims, but it seems there is no example of procedure to dynamically verify which scopes must be attached to a token based on the role of an authenticated user.

I'm looking for an answer dedicated to Curity.io solution and the recommanded best practices to adapte scopes based on a given user role in a web app using RBAC, to secure the calls to the APIs during the user journey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of scenario is usually managed as follows:

- Scopes are application level privileges set at design time, and are requested before the user is known
- Claims are identifiers with user specific values set at runtime, once the user has been identified

**MULTIPLE ROLES APP DESIGN**

Personally I would look to model the authorization around the mainstream use case:

- Customers can buy things and look at products, and this constitutes the majority of app usage
- There is an internal admin operation to update products, which is an exception

This might lead to the following API authorization code:

```
updateProduct(input: Product) {

   if (!this.hasScope('product') || !this.hasRole('admin')) {
       throw new ForbiddenError();
   }

   this.repository.updateProduct(input);
}
```

I think my personal preference for your use case would be to use the below values:

- Scope: product_read
- Claim: (role=customer)

You may prefer to call this scope `product` or `product_write`. It is true to say that the app has scope to a product but that exact permissions are not known until the user's claims are identified.

**APP PER ROLE DESIGN**

At one previous company we used to design separate apps for each `persona`, since the security and UX effort sometimes varied between the two cases:

- The main internet app for customers, with `scope=product_read`
- An internal UI for administrators, with `scope=product_write`

This enables each app to get different scopes. You can't get different scopes per user within the same app though.

Comment: Hi @gary-archer, thank you very much for your previous answer to this question two years from here. The question was about dynamically adapting scopes based on a user role contained in its SCIM attribute. Once the user as registered through the html-form, the scopes defined for a given client are all returned. So how can we reduces the returned scopes based on its role ? Using one html-form authenticator by role doesn't scale well. We can't adapt requested scopes before asking for the token as the user role isn't known. So how can we do that in Curity ? Through token procedure ?

Comment: You can't use scopes in that way in any identity system. You need to issue claims that are different per user. Then implement API authorization using scopes and claims together.